# How to Add Fitness Limit as Stopping Criterion in Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I added fitness limit into field 'options' in genetic algorithm code and defined its value to be 0.5.

```
clc
clear all
global x1e x2e x3e x1r x2r x3r alfa12 alfa13 alfa23 
%LLE podatci - ekstrakcija aromata smjesom TTEG i vode - 6 komponenata (heptan) na 60°C 
%eksperimentalni podatci - ekstrakt
x1e = [0.0140   0.0175  0.0163  0.0188  0.0181  0.0227  0.0228  0.0214  0.0191  0.0208];
x2e = [0.0729   0.0696  0.106   0.1041  0.1107  0.0931  0.0732  0.0739  0.113   0.069];
x3e = 1 - x1e - x2e;
%eksperimentalni podatci - rafinat
x1r = [0.689    0.6289  0.485   0.4727  0.4332  0.6831  0.6967  0.6553  0.4507  0.6139];
x2r = [0.275    0.2855  0.4418  0.3501  0.4056  0.313   0.2716  0.271   0.4436  0.253];
x3r = 1 - x1r - x2r;
%Optimizacija NRTL parametara - Metoda Sorensena i Arlta
%1. stupanj optimizacije - opis fazne ravnoteze - geneticki algoritam
%parametri neslucajnosti
alfa12 = 0.3;
alfa13 = 0.3;
alfa23 = 0.2;
rng default
%definiranje strukture problema 
OF_A = @OF_2_6H_60C;
problem.fitnessfcn = OF_A;
problem.nvars = 6;
problem.options = optimoptions('ga','FitnessLimit',0.5);
[x,fval] = ga(problem)
```

However, after running code I get following result:

```
Optimization terminated: average change in the fitness value less than options.FunctionTolerance.
x =
    6.1833    5.3657    2.3855    0.6108    2.6711    2.4970
fval =
    0.9834
```

Matlab used function tolerance (default setting) as stopping criterion and not fitness limit even though I added FitnessLimit in field options. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because it stopping on the function tolerance is the default. Try increasing that threshold in order to ensure the fitness limit trips before the tolerance one.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-the-genetic-algorithm-works.html#f6243 I found out that algorithm stops as soon as any stopping criterion is satisfied and there are many. This setting has no sense because: 1) There are many criteria in GA
2) Adding criterion you want is meaningless since algorithm will nevertheless stop on first one which is satisfied
3) GA is used to find function minimum and it has no sense that algorithm stops as soon as possible since method is numerical and we want to get as close to minimum as possible.
Matlab should change this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).